# How to add result rows to json object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Im using ajax to update my data. Ajax calls my function.php where i use a switch to determent which function to run. I save my results in a json object ($resp = new stdClass).
But how do i save multiple rows (with multiple columns) into the json object?

```
function func1($mysqli){
    $result = $mysqli->query("select * from order");

    ///how do i fetch all rows in a loop and save it correctly to my json object?

    return json;
}

$resp = new stdClass;

if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
    switch($_POST["action"])) {
    case "func1":
        $resp->data = func1($mysqli);
        break;
    }
}
echo json_encode($resp);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the function which stores rows in an array and returns it. If query fails, `null` is returned.

```
function func1($mysqli){
    $result = $mysqli->query("select * from `order`");

   if ($result){
     $data = array();

     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
       $data[] = $row ;
     }

     return $data ;

   } else {
     return null ;
   }
}
```

In your code you already save a return value in a `STDClass`, so it is fine:

```
case "func1":
    $resp->data = func1($mysqli);
    break;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input, first of all i see the first thing playing with me is i need ´´ around order! :)

Comment: Oh yes, well noted :) `ORDER` is a reserved word in MySQL

Comment: yes - thanks mate :) though i get: "mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource"

Comment: oo, i think something is happening now! :D

Comment: Just use the code I posted above. If you want to utilize OOP, then `$result->fetch_assoc()` is right. Otherwise: `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)`

Comment: aha, i can see it gets all the rows in console, but im having a hard time outputting them?

Comment: Well it is a different question. Outputting is pretty simple, you will need to decode `json` in javascript and append rows to a tag inside a loop like this: `for (var i in obj.data){}`